# Function that is truncated at some point

Tags: functions

I would like to know what it would mean for a function $f(x)$ to be truncated at point, say $x=3$. This is the first time I came across such an expression and English is not my first language. When I tried to google it all I could find was the statistical distribution that can be "truncated" and there it means that some part of the distribution was removed. My guess would be that $f(x)$ that is truncated at point $x$ is simply not defined at that point? Or is there more to that story?

Comment: Where did you encounter this? Could you provide some additional context?

Comment: That is not a standard phrase in English.  I have heard of, say, power series being truncated at a certain degree, for instance.  Can you please provide the example you are looking at?

Comment: @vvgirl, it appeared in a check-yourself type of question after the lecture.

Comment: @lulu, yeah that is what I thought as I found it very hard to find it used anywhere online. I believe what he meant was that the function is not defined. To give you a better perspective, we talked about truncated Poisson but the question seemed more general. I just thought it might be more complex concept or something. Anyway, thanks for your answers!

Comment: Well, a truncated Poisson is an example of a truncated distribution, and you said you were familiar with that concept.

Comment: A simple example of a truncated Poisson:  A restaurant with a capacity for $25$ (and a single seating) gets a number of guests each minute determined by a Poisson process with some mean $\lambda$.  In terms of $\lambda$, what's the probability that people will be turned away?  The distribution of diners in the restaurant is truncated because there is no possibility of having $26$, or anything greater.